Using System.in to process piped in data AND to await user input
I have a program in java that I would like to be able to attend to piped in data (as in, '(echo "dor = 4"; echo "dor * 2") | program'. That said, it seems System.in only works as an 'indefinite'
stream when used it starts empty, as accepts user input for as long as I like. When I use it to process piped in data, it basically ends after doing so.
After many a hour of suffering, I have come to the conclusion that using tools such as Scanner(System.in) (or RufferedReaders) to process piped in data doesn't allow me to use the System.in stream to wait for user input. When I run the program without piping data into it, using sc.nextLine() after declaring 'Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)' simply blocks while it waits for user input, as I want it to, but when I do pass data into it, nextLine() simply gives me an error ("java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found").
Short of having to choose between one or the other, what can I do here?

There is only one standard input stream. You need to think of other ways of taking input. How about showing a GUI, reading from a file, getting it from the command line arguments? Lots of options here.

Like @Sweeper I would use 2 input streams in Java. It would seem clearer to me. However, if you insist, you may play around with something like cat someFile.text - | program where someFile.text contains the output from your echo commands. The hyphen - denotes standard input and instructs cat to read from there after having read the file.

Can you show the example with nextLine? Normally  that should return null when the end of the stream is reached.

@dan1st  the only standard class that offers nextLine() is Scanner, it does not return null but throws NoSuchElement if trying to read after the end of the input (different from InputStreams)

My fault. I mean BufferedReader#readLine. For Scanner  it would be necessary to check hasNext or similar.

Sounds like you should be building your own command intepreter, along with shell prompt... Near to jshell of course

@Anonymous your suggestion seems to be a workaround, it indeed allowed me to read from both sources. Can you explain me why I can use the System.in input stream normally when I pipe content to my program with cat someFile.text - ?

@dan1stmightbehappyagain the error I got is exactly what user8541 pointed out: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found. I would just like to know why the input has an end when I pipe content into my program, while it doesn't "have an end" and simply waits for my input when I run my program without piped in data.

if you pipe it, the input ends when the program on the left side of the pipe terminates. In interactive mode (user interacts with the console), that typically doesn't happen (the user can end the input with Ctrl+D in most linux terminals)

You can write your application so that it first reads input from System.in and, when that stream closes, it starts reading input from java.io.Console
for (Reader reader : new Reader[] { new InputStreamReader(System.in), System.console().reader()) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        process(line);
    }
}

Note, however, that this is very unconventional. Users typically expect an application to read either from a pipe or from standard input, not one after the other.
